# AWS security certificate

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ssl-certificate

In Amazon EC2, I'm trying to create a load balancer, and I got to a step where it says that I need a certificate. It gives me three options:

1.Choose an existing certificate from AWS Identity and Access Management (cannot click on this for one reason)

2.Upload a new SSL certificate to AWS Identity and Access Management

3.Choose an existing certificate from AWS Certificate Manager

I do not know how to do anything if I choose to upload a new SSL certificate, and If I choose to choose an existing certificate from AWS manager, no certificates come up for me to choose.

I cannot skip this step. Im trying to make an app, and this server is crucial. What do I do?

Answer (score 1):

Installing an SSL certificate on ELB *without* using AWS Certificate Manager can be a frustrating task for someone unfamiliar with the techniques and terminology involved in working with SSL certificates.

Certs, chains, and keys actually turn out to be pretty simple concepts but it is not easy for neophytes to find straightforward and correct answers.  The initial steps, the reasons why you do them, and what observations and decisions you have to make based on various conditions you might encounter could fill an entire book.  (For example, some certificate authorities send you multiple certificates for the chain, which you have to assemble in the correct order, others will actually assemble the chain for you upside down, requiring you to reassemble it correctly.  You need to be able to understand this condition and sort it out.  Also, the console indicates the chain is optional, but that is almost never actually true except when using a self-signed certificate for testing, and omitting it can give you the false impression that your setup is correct when, in fact, it isn't.)

Unless you use Amazon Certificate Manager (ACM, see below), it is actually beneficial, while learning, to skip this step and not enable SSL at all, when initially setting up the balancer, because you will not necessarily realize you got it wrong until the end of all the steps, when creating the load balancer fails, and you have to start over.  So, do skip this step by **not** initially trying to set up SSL when setting up the ELB.  You can go back and add it, after the balancer is created.

**If working with SSL certificates is unfamiliar to you, use Amazon Certificate Manager.**  It's a free service, sort of a bonus for ELB or CloudFront customers, and manages all the complexity for you.

Go to ACM in the console, selecting the same AWS region where you'll be deploying ELB.  Create the certificate you need, and follow through the verification steps until the certificate had been issued.  Then, when setting up ELB, you will be able to choose the ACM option and select your new cert from the list, which will no longer be empty.

Comment: It says I need to put in my companies website. We don't have an official one, we have one on tumblr, but I don't think we can use that. What now?

Comment: Where do you see this? In ACM?  It's most likely talking about the **new** web site that you're deploying on the ELB.  The one you need the certificate for.

Comment: Well, I'm creating an app.

Comment: Okay, so your app will be accessing the instances behind the ELB using `https://some-hostname.example.com`.  That's what goes here. You have to have a hostname in a domain you control, in order to use HTTPS, so if you don't have a domain, you may need to register a new one, which can be done with many different registrars, but the simplest when integrating with ELB will be Route 53.

Comment: Does the website just need to be the domain name or do I already need to have stuff on the site when I register it?

Comment: The site doesn't exist until you register the domain, so... no, you don't need stuff on a site in order to register a domain.   Registering a domain secured that name for your exclusive use in the Internet as long as you pay the annual registration fee, which is something like $12/yr for a `.com`.  Actually using the domain for launching sites, services, etc., is unrelated to the registration process.

Comment: Alright, sorry just one more thing, It says it sent a verification email to me, but I haven't gotten it. I checked my spam mail and promotions, its not there either. Im not sure if I'm using the right email address. Im using the address i registered the domain with. Am I supposed to use the website email (I.E. "admin@mywebsitename.com")? I can't find a way to login to that.

Answer (score 0):

You only need to upload certificate if you are using SSL/HTTPS.
If you dont need SSL/HTTPS use on HTTP forwarding.

Else you can generate self-signed certificate using this commands

```
openssl req -x509 -nodes -days 365 -newkey rsa:2048 -keyout privateKey.key -out certificate.crt
```

Verifiy the key and certificate is working by using this command

```
openssl rsa -in privateKey.key -check
openssl x509 -in certificate.crt -text -noout
```

Now convert the files to comply with aws certificate requirement.

```
openssl rsa -in privateKey.key -text > private.pem  
openssl x509 -inform PEM -in certificate.crt > public.pem
```

Use above generated files with ELB

Comment: How do I insert it? Do I just copy and past the numbers?

Comment: paste*. Also, which is the public key? Can't seem to find it

Comment: Yes you have to copy paste content of files private.pem and public.pem